# Changing WSS 3.0 to point to a new SQL instance

Tags: backup, sharepoint, team-foundation-server, wss-3.0

I'm testing a failover procedure using a mirrored data tier for TFS 2008 with WSS 3.0 on top of SQL Server 2008. I have been following the instructions at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa980627.aspx but when I got to the "Redirect Web Sites for Team Projects" step I could not connect to Sharepoint Central Administration.

I first got the error "Cannot connect to the configuration database" then after a restart just got 404 errors. I checked the Event Viewer on the app tier and discovered that Windows Sharepoint Services is still pointed to the old database server. It looks like I could use stsadm to change the mapping, but I'm encountering errors I think because I am using named instances.

I'm trying to use this command:

`stsadm -o renameserver -oldservername SERVER1 -newservername SERVER2\TFS`

And have tried different combinations of specifying the instance name or not without success. I'm still trying to figure out why the TFS guide doesn't mention any of this -- how is Sharepoint supposed to find the new database instance or even run Central Administration if all of the databases have been moved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The community content in the following page helped me out: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512723.aspx

Had to get the DBA to set up an alias, then didn't need to run stsadm at all in order to get Central Administration running again.

Comment: This question and answer (recently asked here) may also provide some additional assistance, as well: http://serverfault.com/questions/66818/66836#66836.